# examples for some options for the 'solutions' environment?

Tags: exsheets

Can anyone give an example of how to use the *'pre-hook'*, *'post-hook'*, *'pre-body-hook'* and *'post-body-hook'* options for the solutions environment of the `exsheets` package please?

They don't seem to do anythig for me no matter what I added after the '=' sign so I presume I'm not using them right. There are no examples in the documentation for these 4 options. I included an MWE for convenience and to show how I tried to use those options. Any other MWE will do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  Q1-foo
\end{question}
\begin{solution}[ pre-hook = , post-hook = , pre-body-hook = , post-body-hook = ]  
  S1-foo
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
    Q2-foo
\end{question}
\begin{solution}  
    S2-foo
\end{solution}

\printsolutions
\end{document}
```

Comment: The hooks are not saved for a solution, only the body itself is. The hooks work fine as you see when you add the option `print` to the list

Comment: Oh, that's why they didn't appear to work. Thanks.

Comment: @clemens Would you make it an answer please? :)

Comment: @yo' sure, done :)

Answer (score 1):

The manual should probably make this clearer: the contents of the hooks is typeset when a solution is typeset, i.e., when the option `solution/print` is set to true. However, they are not saved as a part of the solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  Q1-foo
\end{question}
\begin{solution}[print, pre-hook =a , post-hook =x , pre-body-hook =A , post-body-hook = X]
  S1-foo
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  Q2-foo
\end{question}
\begin{solution}[print]
  S2-foo
\end{solution}

\printsolutions

\SetupExSheets{
  solution/pre-hook =a ,
  solution/post-hook =x ,
  solution/pre-body-hook =A ,
  solution/post-body-hook = X
}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

The thought behind those hooks was to allow things like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets,mdframed}

\SetupExSheets{
  solution/pre-hook = \mdframed ,
  solution/post-hook = \endmdframed
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  Q1-foo
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  S1-foo
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  Q2-foo
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  S2-foo
\end{solution}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```